# `iterator` and `const_iterator` for C arrays in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, iterator

Is there a way to get either an `iterator` and a `const_iterator` from both C arrays and C++ STL containers?

I have this template:

```
template <typename T>
class Another_template {
     // implementation
};

template <typename Container>
Another_template<typename Container::iterator>
fun(Container&) {
   // implementation
}
```

I would like the above function to work for C arrays, too.  Is it possible?  Or should I specialize it for C arrays?

I know that C++ has `std::array`, but I am curious about C arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use standard functions `std::begin`, `std::end`, `std::cbegin`, `std::cend` declared in header `<iterator>` with arrays and standard containers.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

template <typename Container>
auto f( const Container &c ) ->decltype( std::begin( c ) )
{
    for ( auto it = std::begin( c ); it != std::end( c ); ++it )
    {
        std::cout << *it << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return std::begin( c );
}

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    f( a );

    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    f( v );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
```

EDIT: You changed your original code snippet nevertheless you may use the same approach. Here is an example

```
template <typename Container>
auto f1( const Container &c ) ->std::vector<decltype( std::begin( c ) )>;
```

Comment: Right.  Regrettably, I had simplified my example too much.  I have fixed it.  As you can see now, I need `iterator` to instantiate another template, therefore `auto` won't work, AFAIK.  Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the functionality of a C array, you can use an stl vector and use it like a c array by getting a reference to the first element:

```
int *c_array = &my_int_vector[0];
```

Comment: The standard way to do this is to use Container<type>.data() 
to get a pointer to the internal array for array-based containers to interface with C functions. This is done most often with strings.